# How to use OpenLayers with react-starter-kit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, openlayers-3, webpack

I have a problem with running OpenLayers3 Map in a project based on [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit). I'm trying to add simple map to react component. What I did was to:

1. Run `npm install openlayers`
2. Add `import ol from 'openlayers'` to `ContactPage.js`
3. Create simple map

   ```
   componentDidMount(){
     var map = new ol.Map({
       target: 'map',
       layers: [
         new ol.layer.Tile({
           source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
         })
       ],
       view: new ol.View({
         center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
         zoom: 4
       })
     });
   }
   ```
4. Add a div to jsx part of render function `<div id="map" className="map"></div>`
5. Run npm start.

I get an error:

```
...\node_modules\openlayers\dist\ol.js:7
    module.exports = factory();
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'geolocation' in undefined
    at C:\Git Repos\traces\node_modules\openlayers\dist\ol.js:160:823
    at OPENLAYERS (C:\Git Repos\traces\node_modules\openlayers\dist\ol.js:7:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Git Repos\traces\node_modules\openlayers\dist\ol.js:13:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Git Repos\traces\build\webpack:\external "openlayers":1:1)
```

This looks like a webpack connected [issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3162) in OL3 which was discussed and fixed. However it still doesn't work for me.

I also tried to add script tag with OL3 directly to `index.html` and removed import of ol in components. This approach works, although I'd like to use Webpack to take care of dependencies.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

One year later, I created this minimal wrapper
[react-openlayers](https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers).

It is a minimal [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) 
wrapper of [OpenLayer 3+](https://openlayers.org/)
written in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)